# How do I go about creating a mapping reduction?

Tags: reductions

So I understand what a mapping reduction is and how to create them for simpler problems such as a reduction from the set of even numbers to set of odd numbers however, seemingly more complicated questions trip me up such as the following...

A and B are computable languages where B is non trivial give a mapping reduction from A to B.

So my thought process with this question is that the reduction must have something to do with the fact that B is non trivial, but I'm not sure.

Any help understanding mapping reductions and this question would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/134475/can-you-reduce-every-decidable-language-to-a-regular-language?

Answer (score 0):

Language C is non-trivial if both C and its complement are non-empty.  If A is non-trivial and B is trivial, there cannot be a reduction from A to B.