# $A$ and $B$ two decision problems.If $A\le\ B$ then $\overline{B}\le\overline{A}$ is true?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, complexity-classes

I have proved that $\overline{A}\le\overline{B}$ is true, but I have no idea how to prove or disprove the opposite direction.

Comment: (Is $\lnot B\le \lnot A$ the complement of $B \le A$? (didn't get \overline to show consistently in a comment))

Answer (score 2):

The claim is false. There are several ways to show it. Note that if $\overline{B} \leq_m \overline{A}$, then $B\leq_m A$ (this is what you've shown). Hence, if by contradiction the claim is true, then we can write it as $A \leq _m B \to  B\leq_m A$, which is clearly wrong. Why? because it simply says "if $B$ is harder than $A$, then $A$ is harder than B". Hence, an immediate classical counter-example would be, an "easy" problem $A\in \text{R}$, and a "hard" problem $B\notin \text{R}$.

**Edit:** I focused on the intuition that you should have when reading such claims. If you do not see immediately why what I wrote serves as a counter-example, then I suggest to think about it, or you can note that [every non-trivial language is $R$-hard](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/134475/can-you-reduce-every-decidable-language-to-a-regular-language).

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $A = \emptyset$ and $B = \{0\}$. A reduction $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is the function $f(x) = \varepsilon$ since $x \not\in A$ (regardless of the choice of $x$) and $\varepsilon\not\in B$.
However $0 \not\in \overline{B}$ and there is no function $g$ such that $g(0) \not\in \overline{A} = \Sigma^*$, hence there is no reduction from $\overline{B}$ to $\overline{A}$.